# Infinite sum convergence proof

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

**Question**: Is my proof of the theorem below vaild?

**Theorem:**

If $\sum a^2_k $ and $\sum b^2_k $ both converge, then $\sum a_k b_k$ converges.

**My proof:**

Assume $\sum a^2_k $ and $\sum b^2_k $ both converge.

There are two cases, namely $\sum a^2_k \le \sum b^2_k$ or $\sum a^2_k \ge \sum b^2_k$.

$\sum a^2_k \le \sum b^2_k \implies \vec a \cdot \vec a \le \vec b \cdot \vec b \implies \lvert \vec a \rvert^2 \le \lvert \vec b \rvert^2 \implies \lvert \vec a \rvert \le \lvert \vec b \rvert$

$\sum a_k b_k = \vec a \cdot \vec b \le \lvert \vec a \rvert \lvert \vec b \rvert \le \lvert \vec b \rvert \lvert \vec b \rvert = \vec b \cdot \vec b = \sum b_k^2$

By the comparison test, $\sum a_k b_k$ converges.

Similarly, $\sum a_k b_k$ converges when assuming $\sum a^2_k \ge \sum b^2_k$.

Hence, if $\sum a^2_k $ and $\sum b^2_k $ both converge, then $\sum a_k b_k$ converges. *Q.E.D*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to observe that $2|a_kb_k|\le a_k^2+b_k^2$ ([AM-GM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means)) now $\sum a_kb_k$ converges by [comparison test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_comparison_test).

---

I would avoid using a vector $\vec a = (a_1,a_2,\cdots)$ (which does not have a finite dimension). Especially when we have an easier solution.

If you want to improve your solution, you can invoke Cauchy's criterion to get a finite sum $\sum_{i=n}^{m}{a_i^2}$ and similarly for $b_k$ and apply the same procedure (here the vector is of finite dimension).

Answer (score 1):

**Proof:**

Assume that $\sum a_k^2$ and $\sum b_k^2$ both converge.

$0\le(\lvert a_k\rvert - \lvert b_k \rvert)^2 = \lvert a_k\rvert^2 - 2\lvert a_k\rvert \lvert b_k\rvert + \lvert b_k\rvert^2 = a_k^2 - 2\lvert a_k b_k\rvert + b_k^2$

$\implies 2\lvert a_k b_k \rvert \le a_k^2 + b_k^2\implies \lvert a_k b_k \rvert \le a_k^2 + b_k^2$

$\{\lvert a_k b_k \rvert\}_{k=0}^\infty$ and $\{a_k^2 + b_k^2\}_{k=0}^\infty$ are two positive sequences.

$\sum (a_k^2+b_k^2) = \sum a_k^2 + \sum b_k^2$ converges.

Therefore, by the comparison test, $\sum \lvert a_k b_k \rvert$ converges.

By definition, $\sum a_k b_k $ is absolutely convergent.

Hence, $\sum a_k b_k $ converges. *Q.E.D*